# Implementing a DIV as a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How you would use jQuery to implement a div that executes  a link when clicked.  It's easy enough to do this in HTML, as shown below, but it seems that a jQuery solution might also be available.  I'm not sure, though, how to execute the link to another URL in jQuery.

```
div#download {
    width:200px;
    height:75px;
    background-image:url(../../images/download.png);
}
a#dwnld {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}


<div id="download">
   <a id="dwnld" href="../../pay_form.php?pn=10"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: do not use jquery for tasks which are meant for html/css

Comment: Are you asking how to make a `<div>` element function like an `<a>` element, using JavaScript to handle the click event and load another page (the way an `<a>` would do automatically)? Or are you asking about how to style a `<div>` to look like an `<a>` element (or vice versa)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
div#dwnld {
    display: block;
    width:200px;
    height:75px;
    background-image:url(../../images/download.png);
}

a#dwnld {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

This should work for you.

Comment: Huh? `div` has always been `display: block` by default, and you're mixing up the two elements' IDs. (Also you have a syntax error.)

Comment: @BoltClock and @nnnnnn are right. And, you don't need both declarations. You only need to merge those styles and use them on the `a#dwnld`. See my solution below. Having both the `div` and `a` is redundant... :(

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure , maybe you must use Trigger function in JQuery like this :

```
$("#download").click(function (){
    $("#dwnld").trigger("click");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This'll work for your current HTML:

```
$('#download').on('click', function() {
  $('a', this).trigger('click')
});
```

Why exactly can't you make your link a `display: block` and make it function like a `<div>`?

Answer (score 0):

this will find the `href` and redirect (`window.location`) on click

```
$('#download').click(function(){
    window.location = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Click on `div` leading to another site

After properly preparing DIV, you can just simply put this:

```
jQuery('.div-as-a-link').on('click', function(){
    window.location = jQuery(this).data('url');
});
```

This will work for **every `div` element with "`div-as-a-link`" class, that has `data-url` attribute set to the location of the site you want to go**.

The demonstration is here: http://jsfiddle.net/tadeck/LQu4v/

### Full code of the solution

The **example HTML** is:

```
<div class="div-as-a-link" data-url="http://en.wikipedia.org/">
    This is a link that after being clicked leads you to some site.
</div>
```

where the **most important parts** are **the class** (so we can distinguish clickable divs from the other divs) and **`data-url` attribute** containing the URL we want to visit after clicking specific div.

You can also separately **make these specific `div`s appear differently** (eg. with `pointer` cursor):

```
.div-as-a-link {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

And finally there is **a JavaScript that binds events to existing `div`s with `div-as-a-link` class**:

```
jQuery('.div-as-a-link').on('click', function(){
    window.location = jQuery(this).data('url');
});
```

And this is all you need :)

### Disclaimer

But remember: `<a>` elements are for links, `<div>`s are not. `<div>`s are used for grouping elements or for styling purposes and **should be used when no other element is available** (in this case you have another element available: `<a>`, just style it properly).

See this for more details: [Mozilla Developer Network: `div`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Element/Div)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#dwnld {
  background-image:url(../../images/download.png);
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 75px;
}

<a id="dwnld" href="../../pay_form.php?pn=10"></a>
```

My other answer and Tadeck's answer should do what you want *if* you were interested in using jQuery. Everyone else's answers address a different issue regarding best practices.

Ideally if you have a link that opens a new page, you want to just use a regular old anchor tag. If you need it to display a background image with a certain width and height, you don't need the div. You just need to style your anchor as a block-level element.